# regarding tensorflow package installation in different conda environments

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I have installed tensorflow 1.15 in a seperate conda environment., and installed tensorflow2 in another environment.,but in both environments it shows the version as 2.1. I dont know why,I need 2 different versions for 2 environments.Please help me fix this.

Comment: You are providing too little information for anyone to help you. Give a full account of what you exactly did, on which system and how the system did respond. From this question it is impossible to guess what went wrong.

Comment: actually I am working on a hand sign recognition  project on an environment ,I used tensorflow 2.1 for it and due to an error i just downgraded to tensorflow 1.15 ,then it worked fine .So when i downgraded the version of tensorflow i believed that this could only affect that particular environment (as in the documentation).Now i want to start a new project that needs tensorflow 2.1,so i created another conda environment,in there I installed tensorflow 2.1 .

Comment: My problem is now when i run that old project(hand recognition) it shows the same error that appeared before.I checked the version of TF in that environment it showed me 2.1 . it should be 1.15 right?

Comment: when I installed TF 2.1 in a seperate conda environment it affects my previous environments,i dont know why